# OracleDataAdapter.Fill "Connection must be open" error

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g, odp.net

I have some code that uses ODP.Net

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
  connection.Open();
  boxCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);

  OracleDataAdapter boxAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(boxCommand);
  DataTable boxTable = new DataTable();        

  boxAdapter.Fill(boxTable);
}
```

I then get an error below on a production server. The test server is fine.

[image: Error Image]

I don't understand as its complaining about a connection not being open but if there was a problem it should occur at the point my `Open` is called not on the `Fill`. Also I thought `Fill` was supposed to open the connection anyway.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on?

**UPDATE: From the comments I tried adding this but same problem:**

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
  connection.Open();
  while(connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
  {
     connection.Close();
     connection.Open();
  }
  boxCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);

  OracleDataAdapter boxAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(boxCommand);
  DataTable boxTable = new DataTable();        

  boxAdapter.Fill(boxTable);
}
```

**UPDATE 2 : I have added logging and the Validate Connection = true to the connection string and I know the connection state is open, the box command was done, the adapter created and the table created, it definitely errors on the Fill**

Comment: Can you put in a debugging message to write out the value of connection.State?

Comment: I hope that this could be of help [connection-lost-contact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370078/oracle-dataaccess-client-oracleexception-ora-03135-connection-lost-contact)

Comment: Is that your real/actual code, or just an example? (I suspect it is a rigged up example, because `boxTable` would loose scope without being used after filled.) I have the feeling there is some detail missing from the code snippet...

Comment: @rally25rs You are totally wrong, The OP mentioned that the error occurs at the `Fill` not after nor before.. I think the link in Steve's comment explains it all..

Comment: @Steve Why doesnt the Fill open the connection though?

Comment: if the connection is `Broken` then you have to `Close` the connection first before you can `Open` the connection again.

Comment: Are you proposing this? 
                connection.Open();
                while (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Open();
                }

Comment: I guess that will work, did you try it?

Comment: The OP made it sound like this happens *every time*, not on occasion. (The OP doesn't say "sometimes" or "after a while") so I doubted the connection would always be broken from the server every time. Actually I was guessing the "real" code might have been doing the .Fill after the ending curly-brace of the `using` which would have disposed/closed the connection before the Fill happened.

Comment: I will try with the change in the connectionstring as mentioned in the above link. It's difficult to say what's is the best workaround when the error (if there is really an error in ODP) happens inside the Fill method. However, we can only hope that, `Validate Connection = true` is the best way to tell at ODP to check the state of the connection, just before acting on the connection itself.

Comment: I tried my loops as shown in my comment above and same error!

Comment: I also tried using Validate Connection = true and still no joy. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jon - I noticed you accepted my answer, but just wondered, did reinstalling fix your problem (not sure if you did that or just gave up)?

Comment: @dcp Found out the program was referencing 10.2.100 but the Oracle client was 10.1.200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try installing the [latest version of ODP.Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) and see if you still have the problem?  You should be able to run latest ODP.Net even against older Oracle DBs (10g in your case).

**EDIT**:
Since you're restricted to a specific ODP.net version, here are some other things to try:

- Make sure the proper Oracle folders are at the beginning of your system path. For example, I have the Oracle folders at the beginning of my path, like this (I have ODP.net installed in c:\oracle\ora11g and I also have Oracle 10g Express Edition installed, but note that the ODP.net folders are **first**:

  c:\oracle\ora11g\product\11.1.0\client_1;c:\oracle\ora11g\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\oracle\ora10g\bin;

  I've seen situations where Oracle does weird things and won't work properly if the path isn't correct.
- Try reinstalling the specific ODP.net version you are using. This should clean things up and hopefully resolve your issue.

Comment: I can't I'm afraid. The DLL being used here is 10.2.0.100

Comment: @Jon - See my latest edit for some other possible tips. Good luck.